# Which query is the best to find similar matches on a field with lots of terms?

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch

I have a index with a field containing a lot of terms (it's a bio, so it has info like profession, education, hobbies, etc). I would like to use Elasticsearch to query for similar bios of a given one.

I'm using a match query. It's giving me some good results but I'm not sure this is the best approach.

```
GET /jdbc/_search?pretty
{ 
  "query": {
   "match": {
      "bio": { 
        "query": "Jack Reacher, 42, is Vice President of Contoso since 2009. Mr. Reacher is responsible for operations, business, accounting, couching, CEO, worldwide, success, government, experience, MBA, CIO, North America. Previously Mr. Reacher worked as Manager of Operations at ABC Inc. from January 2003 to October 2009. Mr. Reacher holds a Bachelor of Business Administration degree from the University of Michigan and enjoy spending his weekends with his family and friends. His passion beisdes his family is music and his Porsches."
            }
        }
    },

    "size": 20
}
```

Is this the best way to go? Maybe trying to combine with another query would give more precise matches?

I have no intention to use this on a application, since it would be much easier to separate this info in different fields. This is to help me to find duplicated items on a DB; they are a little bit different, but are about the same person.

Answer (score 1):

That approach is fine, as long as, your bios don't get too big(1024 terms). You may have bump this value in your elasticsearch.yml and restart:

```
indices.query.bool.max_clause_count
```

It ends up doing an OR relevance query across all terms, so will end up with likely irrelevant docs towards the bottom of the result set.

There are other options that will likely return more relevant results. For instance, check out the More Like this query:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-more-like-this.html#search-more-like-this

Also, sloppy phrase queries may come in use:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#_phrase

Comment: Hey @ppearcy, thanks for the help! I tried this out but it didn't worked the way I wanted... I ended up combing queries.